# Is there any search integration between Google Apps and HipChat?

Tags: search, google-search, atlassian-crowd

At the moment, I use the google stack with gmail and hangouts, which I can enter one search term and search all my emails and hangout chats at once.

The developers in my team are leaning towards using HipChat for development talk only (pasting stacktraces, sending files, etc). Some other non-developers (account managers, pms, etc) still want to continue to use hangouts.

Is there any integration or tools that will allow me to search my gmail, hangout chats, and hipchat chats, all from one search?

EDIT: fixed typo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, after extensive googling, I have found no clean solution to my problem.

From a small amount of reading, it looks like Zapier *might* be able to help but will require configuration at the very least, and mostly likely will be difficult to roll out across an organisation. In addition, having to rely on a third party company to 'integrate' these apps (if it's even possible) may be problematic, making things much dirtier.

I will look into hitting up the hangout/hipchat feature request pages to see if I have a chance of getting a supported solution from one of the vendors in the future.

Please go ahead and post if anyone has more information around this, which i hope will be the case in the future!